# download file through servlet since internet explorer

Tags: java, internet-explorer, servlets

I have this method for download files through servlet, and works fine on chrome and mozilla but not on Internet Explorer (I try on version 11)

```
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    File downloadFile = new File(filePath);
    OutputStream outStream;
    // gets MIME type of the file
    try (FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(downloadFile)) {
        // gets MIME type of the file
        String mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);
        // modifies response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());
        // forces download
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);
        //response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=60");
        // obtains response's output stream
        outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
    outStream.close();     
}
```

Comment: Could you put a resource online for testing? What response do you see in the F12 Developer Tools under the Network tab when the server responds? This appears to be related to [KB279667](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279667/), do you have all updates installed?

Answer (score 0):

I verify the client side and find that the hiperlink with href wasnt working on explorer, I made the redirect from javascript; the method is that I post is working fine.